# How to choose specific elements from multiple lists in a simple way?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have these two lists (let's imagine we have hundreds of lists) :

```
l1 = list(c(1,2,3),c(12))
l2 = list(data.frame(x=c(1,2,3)),c(4,5))
```

and I wish to choose only the second element from each list. How to do so ? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
f1 <- function(lstobj)
{
   lapply(lstobj, \(x) if(is.data.frame(x)) x[[1]][2] else x[2])
}
```

If it is to extract the second list element

```
f1 <- function(lstobj, ind)
     lstobj[[ind]]
}
f1(l1)
f1(l2)
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the second element of each list, you can use `lapply` with `"[["` and `2`, like this:

```r
l1 = list(c(1,2,3),c(12))
l2 = list(data.frame(x=c(1,2,3)),c(4,5))

lists <- list(l1, l2)
lapply(lists, "[[", 2)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 12
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 4 5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>